# Suffixing the each member of a Java Array of String

Tags: java, arrays, suffix-array

Suffixing of each array member by the same suffix (.wav) is required as:

```
String []  a = {"one", "two", "three"};
String str = ".wav"
```

Required output :

```
String[] a ={"one.wav", "two.wav", "three.wav"};
```

I tried to achieve this in the following way:

```
int m;

     for (m=0; m<a.length ;) {

        a[m]= a[m] +str  ;

     }
```

but I failed. What should I do to achieve the required output?

Comment: "but I failed" doesn't tell us anything about what went wrong. Hint: you're not changing `m` anywhere in your loop... (That's just a matter of not looping properly; it has nothing to do with the body of your loop.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot m++;

```
for (m=0; m<a.length; m++) {

    a[m]= a[m] + str;

 }
```